# Last executed queries for a specific database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I know how to get the last executed queries using the following SQL in SSMS -

```
SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.text AS [Query]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

But I want to find them for a specific database. I don't want to use SQL Profiler, if I don't have to. Plus I don't think SQL Profiler will allow me to view queries that were already run without profiling turned on. I need to do this from SSMS.

Comment: It won't always be populated, so you may miss stuff, but as a start you can filter on `WHERE dest.dbid = DB_ID('your database name')`. If you want to trace going forward, don't *ever* use Profiler unless you want your monitoring to actually contribute to performance problems. Use a server-side trace, extended events, or a 3rd party tool (I know a pretty good one).

Comment: while that executes, it does not get my any row. I have few other databases. Nothing shows for any of them. Maybe it isn't DB_ID('database name').. the ids are different?

Comment: That query above is unusable in determining what all executed because I don't even see some of the db ids of the databases. I used 'SELECT name,database_id
FROM sys.databases;'

Comment: @AaronBertrand Why don't you post your comment as an answer? You answered 6 months before the answer below. I will accept yours.

Comment: How to log query execution data using `server-side trace` or `extended events`?? Can you please brief..

Comment: You can use SQL Profiler for that.

Comment: DB_NAME(dbid) may be used to discover the name of a database from the database id.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

This works for me to find queries on any database in the instance.  I'm sysadmin on the instance (check your privileges):

```
SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.text AS [Query], dest.*
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
WHERE dest.dbid = DB_ID('msdb')
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

This is the same answer that Aaron Bertrand provided but it wasn't placed in an answer.

Comment: This looks into the procedure cache and showing only `CREATE PROCEDURE or FUNCTION` statements, which is useful, but not complete. See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35703/find-all-the-queries-executed-recently-on-a-database

Comment: But this shows me the original sql string without submitted values. Is there any way to show the parameters values supplied to the executed query??

Comment: im  sysadmin . i execute querys from c# sqldataadapter. but no result show up?!

Comment: Which database use for execute query ? ***master, msdb, tempdb*** ?

Comment: This works in SQL Server 2012 and not in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Using ***sys.dm_exec_cached_plans*** ? like `FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats st 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(st.sql_handle) AS sql_text
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp`

Comment: How can I see who has executed the query please?

Answer (score 18):

Following works perfectly for me : hope this helps

```
SELECT
    deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], 
    dest.TEXT AS [Query]
 FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY 
    deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

Comment: This was asked in 2012. You are posting same answer as accepted but slightly inaccurate. -1

Comment: the selected answer did not work for me with SQL 2019 so I shared the above one which worked.

Comment: Yes Jack, original answer works in SQL Server 2019 (replace `msdb` with database of your choice. You answer does not care for `specific database` part of the question. It is therefore, inaccurate. If you add database, and `dest.*` clause from accepted answer to your query, it is identical to accepted answer.

Comment: This worked for me since all sys.dm_exec_query_stats rows have dbid=NULL. I have no idea on why that is, but that means that no matter what I change DB_ID('msdb') to, it won't return any results