# List all queries coming on MS SQL 2008 database

Tags: sql-server-2008, profiler

I want query that list out all queries coming on database or fired on database. Like SQL profiler. I used express profiler software and listing out queries but just for the knowledge I want to know which queries they are using to list out all queries or some other logic they are using... Check below image...

[image]

Comment: This might be helpful:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/01/07/sql-server-find-currently-running-query-t-sql/

Comment: nope its not working... its not displaying all queries like in above image....

Comment: That will show active queries.. For completed queries try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638435/last-executed-queries-for-a-specific-database