# How to retrieve dropped stored procedure, function, table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, select, stored-procedures

**I verified the link below as some one (@Oliver) posted as duplicate of my Question. But this query returns last execution script. It is not related to my question.**

[Last executed queries for a specific database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638435/last-executed-queries-for-a-specific-database)

I have a database with Sample_Training and I created a stored procedure in it and later on I deleted it and now I want to retrieve that deleted stored procedure.

I am employee in company so that I don't have administrative permissions

```
DECLARE @Date_From DATETIME = '2015-01-02'
DECLARE @Date_To DATETIME = '2015-01-05'

SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), SUBSTRING([RowLog Contents 0], 33, LEN([RowLog Contents 0]))) AS [Script]
FROM
    fn_dblog(NULL,NULL)
WHERE 
    [Operation] = 'LOP_DELETE_ROWS' 
    AND [Context] = 'LCX_MARK_AS_GHOST'
    AND [AllocUnitName] = 'sys.sysobjvalues.clst'
    AND [TRANSACTION ID] IN (SELECT DISTINCT [TRANSACTION ID] 
                             FROM sys.fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)
                             WHERE Context IN ('LCX_NULL') AND Operation IN ('LOP_BEGIN_XACT') 
                               AND [Transaction Name] = 'DROPOBJ'
                               AND CONVERT(NVARCHAR(11), [Begin Time]) BETWEEN @Date_From AND @Date_To)
                               AND SUBSTRING([RowLog Contents 0], 33, LEN([RowLog Contents 0])) <> 0
```

By the above query I can get stored procedure and now my question is how to get function, table.

Comment: Since you're *employee of a company*, I'm sure that company is professional enough to have a **source control** system, and you're professional enough to check in your SQL scripts --> just retrieve the script that creates that stored procedure from source control and run it again - done!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Last executed queries for a specific database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638435/last-executed-queries-for-a-specific-database)

Comment: First Check the Query what you mentioned as Duplicate. It will give Last Execution Query. I am not Asking for last execution query. If you have SSMS just run my query and check the result. @Oliver

Comment: http://raresql.com/tag/how-to-recover-the-deleted-stored-procedure/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I got Solution to my question. First Need to create a procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Recover_Dropped_Objects]
    @Database_Name NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Date_From DATETIME,
    @Date_To DATETIME
AS

DECLARE @Compatibility_Level INT

SELECT @Compatibility_Level=dtb.compatibility_level
FROM master.sys.databases AS dtb WHERE dtb.name=@Database_Name

IF ISNULL(@Compatibility_Level,0)<=80
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('The compatibility level should be equal to or greater SQL SERVER 2005 (90)',16,1)
    RETURN
END

Select [Database Name],Convert(varchar(Max),Substring([RowLog Contents 0],33,LEN([RowLog Contents 0]))) as [Script]
from fn_dblog(NULL,NULL)
Where [Operation]='LOP_DELETE_ROWS' And [Context]='LCX_MARK_AS_GHOST'
And [AllocUnitName]='sys.sysobjvalues.clst'
AND [TRANSACTION ID] IN (SELECT DISTINCT [TRANSACTION ID] FROM    sys.fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)
WHERE Context IN ('LCX_NULL') AND Operation in ('LOP_BEGIN_XACT') 
And [Transaction Name]='DROPOBJ'
And  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(11),[Begin Time]) BETWEEN @Date_From AND @Date_To)
And Substring([RowLog Contents 0],33,LEN([RowLog Contents 0]))<>0
```

Execute the procedure as below

```
EXEC sp_Recover_Dropped_Objects 'Sample_Training','2015/12/24','2015/01/07'
```

Comment: Very nice answer. Also this is useful to view what changes happened. http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10718/79884

Comment: I am in the same situation where I need to recover Stored proc dropped by me one hour ago in sql 2014. Could any one help me

Comment: thanks man you save my life

Comment: This didn't work for me.  After some playing around, it seems like this only works for fairly small stored procedures.   I didn't narrow it down exactly but my guess is it only works for Sps smaller then an Nnvarchar(max).