# Will reports creates Objects in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

It's a violation in our business environment to create or modify any changes in SQL Server db's without Change mgmt tickets. Recently, I used SQL Server Standard Reports to view backup and restore events. But my client identified an object has been created in msdb db by running a Audit trace. Please help me in understand what object is he referring and how it is created?

Until I provide a valid justification I'll be in trouble. Please advice

Comment: The client did not provide any details on what object it is that was created?

Comment: Nope and he doesn't know it either :) Per the report, object is created in MSDB

Comment: I think you can script the whole database of a backup, then the whole database for the current DB, and run a schema compare to see what new objects were created.

Comment: Also, take a look at the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638435/last-executed-queries-for-a-specific-database) on StackOverflow about "Last executed queries for a specific database". You can look for CREATE statements in the listed queries. It might be though that what the client sees are temporary tables created by the reports.

Comment: If he doesn't know what the object is, how can he prove it was created?   @TT if it was a temp table, wouldn't it be in TempDb?    OP states it was in MSDB.

Comment: @TabAlleman Good point, he could modify the script for tempdb. I was trying to find a reason why the client claims new objects were created but that they couldn't say what those objects were. That seems like one possible explanation.

Comment: @TT. it seems like the client got the information from default trace using the event id 46. Please help me understand what could be that one possible explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Appears the client gets this information from a default trace using event ID 46. The following statements will determine when objects are created or deleted and who performed those events (taken from [here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/a-few-cool-things-you-can-identify-using-the-default-trace.html)):

```
DECLARE   @filename nvarchar(1000);

-- Get the name of the current default trace
SELECT   @filename = cast(value as nvarchar(1000))
FROM   ::fn_trace_getinfo(default)
WHERE   traceid = 1 and   property = 2;

-- view current trace file
SELECT   *
FROM   ::fn_trace_gettable(@filename, default) AS ftg 
INNER   JOIN sys.trace_events AS te ON ftg.EventClass = te.trace_event_id  
WHERE (ftg.EventClass = 46 or ftg.EventClass = 47)
and   DatabaseName <> 'tempdb' 
and   EventSubClass = 0
ORDER   BY ftg.StartTime;
```

Note: 46 is `Object:Created`, 47 is `Object:Deleted`. You may also want to include 164 which is `Object:Altered` in your query.

Comment: Also you can get information from this [good link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48052/what-event-information-can-i-get-by-default-from-sql-server) on dba.stackexchange.com. GL!