# how to get Transaction History for a SQL server table from SQL server management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to know which update/insert query last executed on a specific table in data base and at what time.

I want to know how to get all transaction(insert/update statement) that got executed on a specific SQl Server Table..

Comment: Actually some contents of my table in SQL Server has got changed and, i need to know by which update/insert command, the table contents got changed.

Comment: msdb.dbo.backupset http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/11/10/sql-server-get-database-backup-history-for-a-single-database/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Last executed queries for a specific database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638435/last-executed-queries-for-a-specific-database)