# Get total count of executed queries in sql server of any database with filtered any date

Tags: sql, sql-server

how can i get the total count of executed queries of any database with in date range. also if it can provide the list of executed queries text, and their execution time. this will help me to optimize my queries.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Last executed queries for a specific database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638435/last-executed-queries-for-a-specific-database)

Comment: This query returned some odd results (most of which were a bunch of sprocs). Moreover, all these results show queries executed since today afternoon (I need queries from data range).
 because it  looks in the procedure cache, and the plans that were used for the morning might no longer live there (due to memory pressure, server/instance restart, manually clearing the proc cache, etc.

Comment: depends on your request "I need queries from data range" use `Where Creation_time between @dateForm and @dateTo`

Answer (score 0):

You can some usage stats by using the below Query

```
-- usage statistics of tables 
DECLARE @dbid int
SELECT @dbid = db_id('your-database-name')

SELECT TableName = object_name(s.object_id),
       Reads = SUM(user_seeks + user_scans + user_lookups), Writes =  SUM(user_updates)
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats AS s
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i
ON s.object_id = i.object_id
AND i.index_id = s.index_id
WHERE objectproperty(s.object_id,'IsUserTable') = 1
AND s.database_id = @dbid
GROUP BY object_name(s.object_id)
ORDER BY reads desc--writes DESC
```