# Disable Sql Server Query logging

Tags: sql-server

I want to disable logging for a specific sql request ( which contains an encryption key in it ) so that if someone asks for the last executed queries in that database ( [Last executed queries for a specific database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638435/last-executed-queries-for-a-specific-database) ) won't have a trace of it. The point is that the secret key should not be stored anywhere after the request is executed.

Is it possible in Sql Server to achieve this ?

Comment: The only way to do this securely is to never transmit the encryption key in the first place. This can be done by keeping the encryption keys in the database (`CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY`, `OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY .. DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE`) or by encrypting the data only on the client side and never giving it to the database in the first place ([Always Encrypted](https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine) is one way to implement that). Anything else is security through obscurity; sysadmins can always pre-emptively trace everything.

Comment: Relevant: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/open-master-key-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks    In this case, you wouldn't need to decrypt with a password

Comment: SQL Server does have logic to mask query text in cases where it contains certain magic strings like "password" (in profiler, deadlock graphs and so on) - I'm not sure that the list of magic strings that will do this is documented anywhere or whether it is comprehensively implemented everywhere that sql text might appear.

Comment: Simple test shows that this does not apply to SQL text in the plan cache so not suitable